# Detecting some strange errors in installation of PETSc on centOS

Tags: gcc, installation, centos, openmpi, petsc

I met 2 problems when I build PETSc as follows:

1. ./configure --prefix=/home/lengjun/softwares/petsc_install
2. make PETSC_DIR=/home/lengjun/softwares/petsc-3.14.1 PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug all
3. make PETSC_DIR=/home/lengjun/softwares/petsc-3.14.1 PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug install
4. make PETSC_DIR=/home/lengjun/softwares/petsc_install PETSC_ARCH="" check

In step 4, it shows that

```
...
*******************Error detected during compile or link!*******************
See http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html
/home/lengjun/softwares/petsc-3.14.1/src/snes/tutorials ex19
*********************************************************************************
...

C/C++ example src/snes/tutorials/ex19 run successfully with 1 MPI process
C/C++ example src/snes/tutorials/ex19 run successfully with 2 MPI processes
*******************Error detected during compile or link!*******************
See http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html
/home/lengjun/softwares/petsc-3.14.1/src/snes/tutorials ex5f
*********************************************************
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.3, needed by /lib/../lib64/liblapack.so, may conflict with libgfortran.so.5
Fortran example src/snes/tutorials/ex5f run successfully with 1 MPI process
Completed test examples
lengjun@localhost petsc-3.14.1]$
```

Other information:
centOS 7
PETSc Version: 3.14.1
MPI implementation:openMPI 4.0.5
Compiler: gcc 8.3.0
Can anyone help me?
Best regards,

Jun